# Is Atomicity still a concern if threads are not used?

Tags: c, multithreading

As far as I know, atomicity (which could be accomplished using locks, which uses memory barriers) are put in place so an operation is either fully done, or not started from the point of view of different threads.

My question is, if we have a single threaded program, is atomicity still a concern?

Comment: no, atomicity makes sense only if there is concurrent access, for example from multiple threads

Comment: If it was a concern no compiler optimisation would be possible. No side effects - no problem.

Comment: One could also write a node.js program which is single-threaded, but asynchronous - and that can modify a shared data structure - and no atomics, memory barriers, or mutexes will help.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, but only in fairly limited situations that essentially involve interacting with another thread that is not part of the single-threaded program or processing outside the CPU such as on a GPU or coprocessor.

For example, consider two instances of a single-threaded program interacting with each other through shared memory. Consider an application interacting with data structures maintained by kernel code that runs in its own thread. Consider an application interacting with data structures in RAM that are also mapped to other hardware such as a video card or transputer.

One other case might be code that could be interrupted by a signal.

Comment: On the topic of being interrupted, hardware interrupts could be another example of a possible avenue for race-condition.

Comment: But the question was if the object is not side effect prone. Then nothing is needed (no atomic access, nor volatile etc)

Answer (score 3):

Atomicity is a concern if the program accesses data that may change asynchronously. Shared data structures are an obvious case of such data, but other examples can be found in single threaded processes:

- memory shared with other processes via `mmap`
- memory accessed by asynchronous signal handlers
- memory mapped hardware registers
- memory updated asynchronously by device drivers

Such data must be declared `volatile` and atomic access is highly preferable to avoid undefined behavior.

If your single threaded process does not have such data, atomic access is not a concern.

Comment: no side effects no atomicyty needed. Otherwise no optimization possible.

Comment: @P__J__:  I'm afraid I do not understand your comment

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing which can change the object outside the normal program execution flow (ie no side effects) the atomicity is not the issue.

Comment: What if something outside the normal program execution flow reads the value and performs an action based on that?  If a program gets interrupted in the middle of a multi-instruction operation, the interrupt service routine could be acting on data that matches neither the before state nor the after state.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, If you're writing interrupt service routines (ISRs) and other code that shares data with ISRs, then you are no longer working entirely within the realm of "single-threaded programming."